# Работа с массивом в SQL

Tags: sql

Есть таблица, к примеру

```
 id | name
  1 | Vasya
  2 | Petya
  3 | Dima
  4 | Oleg
```

С фронта мне приходит массив вида `[2,3]`
Как отобрать записи с `id` соответствующим данным в массиве? То есть получить 2 и 3 строки.

Comment: `WHERE id IN (2,3)`

Comment: Какая у вас БД? Как, куда и в каком виде приходит массив? Решение надо на чистом SQL? Может ли прийти массив с 1000+ элементов?

Comment: Решение Akina мне подходит, спасибо